# retry failed mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I have some requirement that demands to retry mocha failure tests multiple times. Is there any easy way/workaround to do this?

I tried https://github.com/giggio/mocha-retry, but it doesn't seem to work for me with Mocha 1.21.3:

```
  it (2, 'sample test', function(done) {
      expect(1).to.equal(2);
      done();
  });
```

`mocha test/retry.js -g 'sample test' --ui mocha-retry`

Comment: This has the smell of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/241526). Why do you need to retry your tests? (Ok, there's a "requirement that demands" it but why the requirement?) Even the documentation for mocha-retry (which has quite a few typos by the way; doesn't inspire confidence) has a paragraph about how your tests should work consistently.

Comment: Well, teams want to focus on consistent failures first, by reducing the noise of intermittent failures because of unstable but out of control environment settings we are facing.

Answer (score 12):

```js
it(2, 'sample test', function(done) {
    this.retries(2); // pass the maximum no of retries
    expect(1).to.equal(2);
    done();
});
```

If your test case fail than it will re-execute the same test case again until the max no of retries reached or test case get passed.
Once your test case get passed it will jump to the next test case.

Comment: Note: retries is now part of mocha core: http://mochajs.org/#retry-tests

Answer (score 11):

There is possibility to ask mocha to retry failed tests in the console:

```
mocha test/retry.js -g 'sample test' --retries 2
```

Answer (score -2):

`try{}catch` and recursion

```
var tries_threshold = 5;
it(2, 'sample test', function(done) {
    var tries = 0;
    function actual_test() {
        expect(1).to.equal(2);
    }
    function test() {
        try {
            actual_test();
        } catch (err) {
            if (err && tries++ < tries_threshold)
                test();
            else done(err);
        }
    }
    test();
});
```

`try{}catch` will help prevent bubbling up the error until you want it to and so allow you to recursively keep trying.